# Create Vocabularies and Terms with the JSON:API module

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9

I am using the JSON:API module.

I need to create vocabularies and terms through the endpoint, but it is only accepting `GET` requests.

Am I using the wrong route or endpoint?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The question should not only describe what you are trying to achieve, but also what you tried so far. What documentation did you read about that module or the routes it uses? What exactly don't you understand in that documentation? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

JSON:API uses the entity machine names by default.  (You can change the names with the [JSON:API Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) module.)

If you don't know the machine name, you can install the [JSON:API Explorer](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_explorer) module, which will provide you with a nice UI at `http://www.example.com/jsonapi/explorer/app`.  Just install the module and visit the URL for your site and you will be able to check everything that is available by JSON:API.

Comment: Thks. But i need to create vocabularys, but the endpoint doesn't work. the endpoint /jsonapi/taxonomy_vocabulary/taxonomy_vocabulary  no working for Request  POST, PATCH, DELETE, this is only working for Request ytpe GET and filters.

Comment: @ArianaRomero By default, JSON:API only allows GET operations.  You need to enable the setting for POST, PATCH, and DELETE at `/admin/config/services/jsonapi`.