# Create vocabularies with the JSON API

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I found [this identical question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312852/create-vocabularies-and-terms-with-the-jsonapi-module) but it seems to be dead and none of the answers help me. I also don't have enough reputation to ask in a comment, so, since I'm at the end of my rope with this issue, I'm posting my own question.

I'll preface the issue with what I've done as I have put effort into solving this on my own:

I have the additional operations enabled:

[image: I have the additional operations enabled]

I'm using the path `/jsonapi/taxonomy_vocabulary/taxonomy_vocabulary`.

I'm sending the following request body:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "taxonomy_vocabulary--taxonomy_vocabulary",
      "id": "d0a3157e-58ad-7a43-93ff-a9b76f2273b6",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Listing Categories",
        "drupal_internal__vid": "listing_categories"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I get the following response:

```
{
  "jsonapi": {...},
  "errors": [
    {
      "title": "Method Not Allowed",
      "status": "405",
      "detail": "No route found for \"POST /jsonapi/taxonomy_vocabulary/taxonomy_vocabulary\": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, HEAD)",
      "links": {...},
      "source": {...},
      "meta": {...}
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm having no issues creating nodes, terms, or even paragraphs with POST requests, so I'm at a complete loss as to why POST requests to create vocabularies are being denied. I've tried searching various terms to see if this is a known bug with vocabularies, but I haven't been able to find anything, which leads me to suspect that I'm missing something on my end. Thanks in advance

Lastly, I apologize for the tags. I'm not used to asking on stack exchange, so I might be missing something obvious, but I can't seem to actually add relevant tags such as `jsonapi`, `json`, `rest`, `taxonomy`, or `vocabulary`. The only thing close I can add is `taxonomy-terms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vocabularies are config entities, and config entities don't currently allow post operations.

See this issue:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2300677

Comment: Ah, that would do it. Thanks. I didn't know the term "config entity" so I never searched for that.